# Passing micronaut application-yml file as a CLI arg

Tags: java, cloud, micronaut

I want to know if micronaut supports a jvm arg which can be used to pass a specific application.yml file

Something similar to  `-Dmicronaut.env.deduction=false`, e.g `-Dmicronaut.application.yml=application-specific.yml`

==============================================

To expand a bit more about my use case, as there might be a more 'micronaut' way of solving my problem :

I have a test, which I want to run both locally and in the cloud
Some of the config parameters should be different based on the runtime environment

At the moment, **Micronaut** is automatically adding **test** in the list of environments, hence both local and cloud tests are reading the same `application-test.yaml`

I also saw the `TestPropertyProvider` which can be used to dynamically setup properties, but I would rather keep my config in `.yaml` files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if micronaut supports a jvm arg which can be used to
> pass a specific application.yml file

It does.  The JVM arg would be the `micronaut.config.files` JVM system property.  Another approach is that you can assign a value to the `MICRONAUT_CONFIG_FILES` os environment variable.

You didn't ask about this but it is related, you can specify config settings in the test itself if the test provides a `PropertySource`.

All of that is documented at https://docs.micronaut.io/2.2.1/guide/index.html#propertySource.

Comment: As an additional question : 


We run our integration tests in the cloud in a docker container.

We're setting the MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=staging in the docker environment variables, to force our application to read the config values from application-staging.yaml. 

However, micronaut is automatically adding "test" as an environment, and then read the config values from application-test.yaml. 


From the docs, environment variables should have priority compared to deduced environments. 
Any idea why micronaut is giving priority to the values in application-test.yaml?